# scrollIntoView() pushes div behind the chrome url bar at top for iOS

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I want to put my div at the top of page on focus event. But on chrome it hides part of it behind the url search bar at top. On emulator it doesn't have that behavior. 
Following is the javascript:

```
goog.events.listen(
        searchInput,
        goog.events.EventType.FOCUS, function () {
            goog.dom.classlist.add(searchSection, 'focused');
            searchSection.scrollIntoView(false);
        }
    );
```

This is the css for focused div:

```
#searchSection {
position: relative;
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);}

#searchSection.focused {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
position: absolute;
top: 0.07rem;
bottom: 0.07rem;
left: 0.07rem;
right: 0.07rem;
height: 100%;
background: #e8e8e8;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
```

}

How to make sure the div starts at the top and just below the url search bar on chrome.